# How to deal with nullable variables that are not null?

Tags: kotlin, nullable, non-nullable

Consider this piece of code:

```
var foo: Foo? = null

if (foo != null) {
    foo!!.bar()
}
```

If I omit the two !! I get this error:

> Smart cast to 'Foo' is impossible, because 'foo' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

This is about concurrency, right? Well, there is no concurrent code that might change the value of `foo`.

Of course, it works with the two !!. However, I was wondering if this is the most idiomatice way or if there is a better way, without the two !!.

I know I could just `foo?.bar()` in this particular case. But the question is about whether I can treat `foo` as `Foo` instead of `Foo?` somehow after I've checked that it's not `null`.

Comment: not really, your options are assigning it to a `val` within function scope, or use one of scoping functions (`let`, `run`, `apply`, `also`)

Comment: How would I assign it to a val within function scope, so that the val would be of type Foo (not Foo?)?

Comment: "_This is about concurrency, right? Well, there is no concurrent code that might change the value of `foo`_". **You** may know that there's no concurrency, but the **compiler** cannot guarantee that.

Comment: @user1785730, the `val` will be of type `Foo?`. However, now smart cast will work and you won't need `!!` in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this piece of code works if `foo` is a local variable. I guess, your code looks a little bit different and `foo` is a field of a class. The solution is simple: use [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html):

```
foo?.let {
    it.bar()
}
```

`let` "captures" the values of a variable so that any modifications to the original one have no effect in the passed lambda. And safe call is used here to invoke `let` only for non-null values.